# How do I add panels and buttons to the same frame in java using gridlayout?

Tags: java, swing

I want to write Java program using 2 panels and three buttons in the same frame using gridlayout, the first panel should include 2 labels and 1 text field and the second one should include 2 buttons, the two panels done correctly but I cant adding the  three buttons without using panel.

```
public class ConverterGUI3 extends JFrame {

    private JLabel binaryLabel,resultLabel;
    private JTextField inputText;
    private JButton zero,one,toDecimal,toOctal,clear;
    private JPanel panel1,panel2;

    public  ConverterGUI3 () {
      setSize(400,200);
      setTitle("Converter");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      binaryLabel=new JLabel("Binary");
      inputText=new JTextField();
      resultLabel=new JLabel("Result");

      zero=new JButton("0"); 
      one=new JButton("1"); 

      toDecimal=new JButton("Convert To Decimal"); 
      toOctal=new JButton("Convert To Octal");
      clear=new JButton("Clear");

      Container cp=getContentPane();  
      cp.setLayout(new GridLayout());

      panel1=new JPanel();
      panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
      panel1.add(binaryLabel);
      panel1.add(inputText);
      panel1.add(resultLabel);
      cp.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      panel2=new JPanel();
      panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
      panel2.add(zero);
      panel2.add(one);
      cp.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      cp.add(toDecimal, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      cp.add(toOctal, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      cp.add(clear, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ConverterGUI3 frame = new ConverterGUI3();
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

[Converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dho8a.png)

Comment: `GridLayout` may not be capable of doing what you, but it would be helpful to have a picture of what you are tying to do

Comment: Show your code so that we can give correct anwer

Comment: I'm trying to add a picture but is asked me to add 10 reputation sorry I don't understand what it wants but the following is the question:

Comment: That's a good idea of @MadProgrammer for 'picture'.  Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: *"I'm trying to add picture but is asked me to add 10 reputation"*  One way to do it is to upload the image to any image share site, then put the link.  If it is relevant (and small enough) someone else might embed it.  And a Tip: Add @AJ. (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Add a link to the picture, we will import it to the question

Comment: "Develop a public class ConverterGUI to the following specifications:
You are required to build a GUI interface ConverterGUI. It allows the user to input the

• The frame use setDefaultCloseOperation() method to close the widow and
terminates the program when the user clicks on close button.
• The frame has Grid Layout. It consists of two JPanels, and 3 JButtons as:
• Panel1: includes the binary JLabel, the binary JTextField (Non Editable), and the result JLabel.
• Panel2 includes 2 JButtons, to enter 0 & 1."

Comment: That requirement says to set a `GridLayout` to the **frame** but does not specify a layout for the **panels** that are added to the frame.  I would use a single column grid layout in the frame with a **`FlowLayout`** (the default) in each panel.

Comment: I added my code please look at it and tell me where is the faults